# django queryset for grouping and counting

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Details.objects.all()

```
Dept      Gender   Shift
Software  Male     Day
Software2 Female   Night
```

what i want is json like {"Gender":"Male", "count":2} using queryset.
count is the number of male and female in specific dept.

im new to djnago and have tried this

```
Details.objects.values("Gender").annotate(count=Count("Gender")).order_by("Shift")
```

where i get

```
[{'count': 3, 'Gender': u'Female'}, {'count': 1, 'Gender': u'Male'}, {'count': 3, 'Gender': u'Female'}, {'count': 3, 'Gender': u'Male'}]
```

of both departments...I want one dept at a time(Software/Software2). Please help:) Thanks.

Comment: share your expected output format

Comment: {"Gender":"Male", "count":2} this is my expected output. i need to get theie count and gender by dept

Comment: Have you tried `Details.objects.values("Dept", "Gender", "Shift").annotate(count=Count("Gender"))`

Comment: @FazilZaid thank you:) but can u help me make it more precise so i get  
{"Gender":"Male", "count":2} from software dept only.

Comment: Details.objects.filter(dept='Software').values("Dept", "Gender", "Shift").annotate(count=Count("Gender"))

Comment: Then, `Details.objects.filter(Dept='Software').values("Gender").annotate(count=Count("Gender"))` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django ORM makes this quite difficult to do using annotations and aggregates so I opted for a more pure-python approach.

```
from collections import Counter
d = list(Details.objects.values_list('Dept', 'Gender', 'Shift'))
response = [i + (c[i],) for i in Counter(d)]
```

What we are doing is pulling out the rows as tuples and then passing them into a python `Counter` which returns a dict-like object where the keys are the original tuples and the values are a count of the number of tuple occurrences.

This gives:

```
[
    ('software1', 'male', 'night', 2), 
    ('software1', 'female', 'day', 1), 
    ('software2', 'male', 'day', 1), 
    ('software2', 'female', 'day', 1), 
    ('software1', 'female', 'night', 1)
]
```

To dictify the result we run:

```
final = [{'Dept': i[0], 'Gender': i[1], 'Shift': i[2], 'Count': i[3]} for i in response]
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

The following query takes gender and department as input and gives out count as output in JSON.

```
day_male_count = Details.objects.filter(gender='Male', department='Software', shift='Day').count()

night_male_count = Details.objects.filter(gender='Male', department='Software', shift='Night').count()
```

I feel like this may not be what you were asking, is it?

Comment: this gives a count of male in software dept. i want male count who works in software dept at day shift and night shift separetely.

Comment: @meow Changed the answer. Please check now.